# Incorrect value while reading from excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I am reading a value from an excel cell. At the time of reading code converts integer to float values. Below is the code snippet and its input/output values

```
while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    String cellData=cellIterator.next().toString();
                    System.out.println("cellData "+cellData);
                }
```

Input 5                   Output 5.0

Input 4699123912          Output 4.699123912E9

Please help TO PRINT OUTPUT AS INPUT.

Comment: Those two numbers are the same.  The second one represents: 4.699123912 x 10⁹

Comment: Numeric cell values are kept as `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

Those two numbers are the same in Excel.

The second one represents: **4.699123912 x 10⁹**, which is **4699123912**.

The `E` stands for exponent.  The only thing is that it's supposed to have a `+` after the `E` but maybe Java is removing it since it's positive, because:

```
4.699123912E+09 = 4699123912

4.699123912E-09 = 0.000000004699123912
```

Comment: Hi, How to print similar to input?

Comment: excuse me? print what?

Comment: I mean print cellData as similar to input. Presently it prints as floating point value, even in IDE console

Comment: Well, I've never used Java, but it looks to me like you're copying the cell as a String instead of a number like Double.  So find out you would change this `cellIterator.next().toString();`  ... wild guess: `toDouble` ?

Comment: neat, I guessed right: [toString info here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm).  I hope you know the difference between String and numeric types.